# Get text file using function in PHP

Tags: php, file, function

Suppose that I have the PHP function as below:

**function.php**

```
<?php
function getDataInFile($PMTA_FILE){
    $PMTA_DATE = date("Y-m-d");
    $lineFromText = explode("\n", $PMTA_FILE);
    $number_bar_charts = 13;
    $row = 0;
    $cate = "";
    $total ="";
    $fail = "";
    $mailSuc = "";
    $title = "";
       foreach($lineFromText as $line){
            if($row < $number_bar_charts){
              $words = explode(";",$line);
              $dateTime .= ','.$words[0];
                if($title == ""){
                   $title = $words[0];
                }
                $cate .= ','."'$words[5]'";
                $total .= ','.$words[6];
                $fail .= ','.$words[7];
                $mailSuc .= ','.((int)$words[6] - (int)$words[7]);                          
            $row++;
      }   
     }

}


?>
```

This is code below that I call the function to use in `getFile.php`.

```
<?php 
include("include/function.php");
$PMTA_DATE = date("Y-m-d");
getDataInFile("../stats_domain_recepteur.affinitead.net.".$PMTA_DATE.".txt");

?>
```

In fact, it can not read data from the file, I got the error messages `Undefined variable: dateTime in C:\wamp\www\chat\include\function.php on line 15`,`Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\wamp\www\chat\include\function.php on line 19`....

I do not know how to fix this, Anyone help me please, Thanks.

Comment: You have `$dateTime .= ','.$words[0];` ... but `$dateTime` is not defined anywhere. You're trying to append to it without initializing it.

Comment: Wait... I don't see a single function call that would have attempted to open any file to read its content into any variables. So even if you fixed `$dateTime` your code will not work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are Notices only. They are not terrible errors that will blow up your code, but some code reviewers would make you fix them. PHP is just giving you a polite nudge, but will work anyhow. Fatal errors are the big, bad problems that will stop PHP in its tracks.

Here are the problems PHP found...

1. You're appending data to the string $dateTime on each iteration. On the first pass through the variable doesn't yet exist. PHP doesn't really care, but will issue a warning. To get rid of that problem, define $dateTime before you use it.

   `$dateTime = null;`
2. The second problem is an array out of bounds exception. You are trying to do something with $words[5] when that array index doesn't exist. In general, you should check that array indexes, variables and other fun stuff actually exist before you try to use them.

   `$cate .= sprintf(",'%s'", isset($word[5]) ? $word[5] : '');`

If you don't want to see Notices and Warnings reported in the error log, see [PHP Error Handling](http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php) to learn how to set which error levels you want to see in your log.

You should also read all about the [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function to actually get the file in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

add $dateTime = ''; before foreach($lineFromText as $line){

this will works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages are 100% legit: you're trying to use a variable which hasn't been initialized before. Put this code above the loop and you'll get rid of this error:

```
$dateTime = '';
```

Regarding the second error - it tells that you don't have 6-th element in the array, so you'd better replace that code with a check:

```
$cate .= sprintf(",'%s'", isset($word[5]) ? $word[5] : '');
```

Extrapolate this check to other index accesses, as well.